# WSL on Ubuntu 上で VSCode の拡張機能 Live Server が起動しない

Tags: ubuntu, vscode, wsl

## 概要

ubuntuからvscodeを開いてweb開発を試みています。
拡張機能のlive serverを起動しようとしたのですが、open with live server→port:5500の状態になったのに、ブラウザが立ち上がりません。
また、vscodeをwindowsのlocalから立ち上げるとlive serverが起動しました。読み込みも問題ありません。
どうやら、ubuntuからは開けないようです。
どうにかなりませんか…

## 試したこと

https://qiita.com/carbo_jtc/items/eccc6c2f854f7e07a2ef
https://teratail.com/questions/353734

この辺の解決法を一通り試してみたのですが、いずれも効果がありませんでした。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[Live Server Extension in VS Code is not working in WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71073082/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

live serverの設定「use local ip」を有効化することにより解決。

```js
{
  "liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true,
}
```

（自己回答）